# Hash function for indexed objects

Tags: c#, hashset, gethashcode

Say, I have a class which indexes all objects that are created from it from 0, ..., n-1 (using a static counter of created objects). As these objects are used in HashSets and Dictionaries, we need a Hash function.

Is there any reason not to use this index as Hash value?

Comment: It's a pretty vague question, but as long as the index will never change (say if some of them get deleted, for example), it should be a reasonable hash.

Comment: The index would be a perfect hash in this case.

Comment: The reason for asking is that often one hears that a hash function should be "spread out over the integers", but if you generate a thousand objects, is there any harm in giving them hash values from 0 to 999?

Comment: @JFMeier no there is no harm, in fact that is the most optimal spread you can get.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Well, there kind of is.  The default implementation of `GetHashCode` *already* has the semantics of every object instance being unique.  You're overriding the implementation only to provide identical semantics.  Why even *bother*.

Comment: @Servy because you may be pulling from a database with a identity column. You may query multiple times creating different objects in memory, however you could override Equals and GetHashCode to compare that identity column. I agree that for the Op's use case he described in his post there is no reason to override (I upvoted your answer) but in the general case where you would have a index value but the objects are not the same object in memory it would provide a very good hash.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Of course I'm not saying that it never makes sense to override the hash code functionality ever.  I'm simply saying that if you're only using it to base the identity on a value that's unique to that object instance, which he is doing as in the situation he described no two objects will ever share a value) that it has the same semantics as the default behavior.  If he had different requirements, he may obviously need to do something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [actual code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/R/06d905a0ac76e4f5.html) for Contains on a HashSet

```
private int[] m_buckets;
private Slot[] m_slots;

public bool Contains(T item) {
    if (m_buckets != null) {
        int hashCode = InternalGetHashCode(item);
        // see note at "HashSet" level describing why "- 1" appears in for loop
        for (int i = m_buckets[hashCode % m_buckets.Length] - 1; i >= 0; i = m_slots[i].next) {
            if (m_slots[i].hashCode == hashCode && m_comparer.Equals(m_slots[i].value, item)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    // either m_buckets is null or wasn't found
    return false;
}

private int InternalGetHashCode(T item) {
    if (item == null) {
        return 0;
    } 
    return m_comparer.GetHashCode(item) & Lower31BitMask;
}

internal struct Slot {
    internal int hashCode;      // Lower 31 bits of hash code, -1 if unused
    internal T value;
    internal int next;          // Index of next entry, -1 if last
}
```

The key things you want to notice is it calls `GetHashCode()` then it does `hashCode % m_buckets.Length` on the result to figure out which singularly linked list root stored in `m_slots` should it traverse.

The best possible algorithm will give you a even distribution of values across `hashCode % m_buckets.Length` so all linked lists will be the same length. Starting at 0 and counting up does this perfectly, so yes if you can get a fixed index for a object that is unique and just counts up that is a perfect hashcode.

Answer (score 3):

You certainly could use it, but if you did, it would mean that each separate object instance was considered a different object by those hash based structures.  If you want different object instances to be able to be considered "equal" then this method wouldn't work.

If that is in fact your goal there's no reason to override the default equality/hash-code semantics at all.  The default implementation will compare the object references, resulting in each object being "different" from every other object.  So save yourself the effort and just don't bother doing *anything*.

Comment: What about speed? Might it be faster to use an index than using a standard hash function on 64bit references?

Comment: @JFMeier I highly doubt you'd even be able to measure the difference.  There's almost no chance that that is going to take long enough to even spend time evaluating.  There are better places to spend your time if your program is taking too long.

Answer (score 0):

One reason not use the index as a hash functions is because you *want* duplicates across disparate instances.

Say you're using a `Dictionaty` in an Entity system, and your keys are a combination of both Entity and Component type for any given Component. When looking up a Component, you want to be able to create a new key from Entity, Component Type, and have it equate to the key with the same Entity and Component Type. In this way, a statically incrementing index is not the way to go, since it would result in an object representing the same value having a different HashCode, resulting in it being useless as a key in a Dictionary.

Another reason is that you might have an arbitrarily huge number of objects over a type which is run in a program with an extended lifetime - let's say the transaction manager on a database driver. In such a case, you might actually run out of integer values (~4.2 billion values if you allow negatives or use an `uint`). In such a case, the hashcode is not enough to garuantee uniqueness - this is normal behaviour for hash codes, but a very possible gotcha for an overzealous optimization.

Comment: Your int max values are 2x what they should be.